# Тег <style> отсутствует в AIDE

Tags: java, android, aide

Добрый день знатокам мобильного программирования на **Java**.

Сегодня попробовал написать простейшую программу под **Android** на Android, а точнее с помощью программы **AIDE**.

Все бы хорошо, но при попытке использовать стиль и тему с помощью тега

`<style name="" parent="">`

появляется ошибка, в которой пишется `"aapt: Error parsing XML: no element found"`.

В **Android Studio** на ПК все работает.

И как же быть? Без стилей все будет не таким, какое нужно мне. Что делать?

Comment: Предположительно, нужно закрыть тэг так: `<style name="" parent="" />`

Comment: Бесполезно. Все та же ошибка

Comment: К сожалению с AIDE не работал, поэтому только догадками. Может там по другому ресурсы подключаются/обрабатываются? В примерах же должно быть что то аналогичное?!

Comment: Ага, после долгих мучений проблема вроде исчезла. Только вот ресурс, который я хочу прописать, а он дефолтный, так что по идее должен быть. А его нет Вот такой адрес Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar Пишет, что данный ресурс не обнаружен. Как его добавить тогда?

Comment: aapt: Error retrieving parent for item: No resourse found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Все, добился нужного результата. Тему закрываем.